# Custom sublime-build file for python

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I recently started building python scripts in sublime text 3, I wanted to build a custom sublime build script such that it can take input from a file "input.txt" and output it into console or a file "output.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those Linux users who are still looking for a solution to this:

You may make use of the redirection operators '<' and '>' inside the custom build file like this:

```
 {
    "shell_cmd": "python \"${file}\" < inp.txt > out.txt"
 }
```

**Note**: For other platforms one may implement a similar idea.

Answer (score 0):

To take input from a file you must open the file with the `open` function:

```
file = open('file.txt')
```

Then you can read the contents:

```
contents = file.read()
```

If you want to put the content or anything into a file, first create/open the file:

```
file2 =  open('file2.txt', 'w')
file2.write(contents)
```

This will write the value of the variable `contents` into the file.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: I think the OP didn't mean file handling inside the python code itself.